# Meaning of 'well enough'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does 'well enough' mean here? The OED says that it means 'to a reasonable degree' (and looking at the respective definitions of the two constituent words gives a similar meaning), but how can one know something 'to a reasonable degree'. Either one knows something, or one doesn't, right?

> "I know well enough that you have become a fool."

Comment: Sufficiently well

Comment: What is the source of the quote?

Answer (score 2):

Your statement that, "either one knows something, or one doesn't" is not correct.  When it comes to individual pieces of data in isolate this *might*  be true— for example, I could say that "I know that the temperature outside right now is 25℃," but even this bit of information can be known with more or less certainty.  How well do I trust my iPhone for reporting this information?  Do I know where the measurement was taken, and could it vary slightly from where I am?  What's the error bar on that measurement, is it really 25.1℃?  And so forth.

When it comes to more complex pieces of knowledge, the variation becomes even more pronounced.  What does it mean to be a fool?  If you say that a fool acts against common sense, what is common sense?  If we agree on common sense, how sure am I that you, specifically, have violated it?  If I'm sure you have acted against common sense, how sure am I that this is a habitual thing for you, or that it was a simple one-time mistake?

All of these things form a "gradient" of knowledge.  You *can* know something with different levels of certainty and definition.  You can know a person with differing levels of familiarity.  You can know an attribute with different levels of precision.

The sentence in question:

> "I know well enough that you have become a fool."

This says that on the gradient of knowledge I have about you, even considering that it's impossible to know another person 100% perfectly, I have *enough* knowledge to confidently say that you have become a fool.  You weren't a fool, but are a fool now.